# Divs alignment and separation via margin

Tags: html, css

When removing the margin from "div.in"(or when making it auto), it is getting the alignment but with no space among them. However, when I made ".col-lg-4:33%" in @media, it is getting to align them but, at the same time, it is not responding as per the next class definition(i.e ".col-md-6").
Here is the code:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.row {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
div.in {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  float: left;
}
.sub {
  margin-left: 80%;
}
h4 {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-3,
  .col-lg-4 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 950px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .col-md-6 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .coll {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 949px) {
  .col-sm {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
  }
  .col-sm {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```
<h1>random heading</h1>

<div class="row out">
  <div class=" in col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm">
    <div class="sub">
      <h4>sub item 1</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
  </div>
  <div class=" in col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm">
    <div class="sub">
      <h4>sub item 2</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
  </div>
  <div class=" in col-lg-4 col-md-6 coll col-sm">
    <div class="sub">
      <h4>sub item 3</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: i am new here, thanks for making the correct changes

Answer (score 0):

Try to Add bootstrap plugin in your html page and just made below changes. You don't have to write responsive media col-sm or col-md code by urself after adding this plugin.

```
    <h1>random heading</h1>

    <div class="row out">   
<div class=" in col-sm-4">
        <div class="sub">
          <h4>sub item 1</h4>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
   </div> 
  <div class=" in col-sm-4">
        <div class="sub">
          <h4>sub item 2</h4>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>   
</div>  
 <div class=" in col-sm-4">
        <div class="sub">
          <h4>sub item 3</h4>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>   
</div>  
<div class="clearfix"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: i want to do without using bootstrap,